# Twilio CallSid and connection.parameters questions

Tags: android, ios, client, twilio

Twilio's document is not clear on following questions:

- for one audio call, are the CallSids the same in: outgoing side's connection.parameters, incoming side's connection.parameters, the TwML app's initial request, and TwML app's statusEventCallback requests? do I have to use the Rest API to find out the "root" CallSid for the purpose of tracking a single call?
- Will I receive the CallSid parameter in statusEventCallback requests?
- Is there a way to pass contextual info as parameters from outgoing side to incoming side only throw TCDevice.connect?
- How to extend the timeLimit to a one-to-one call? I saw examples to do conference call. Is it the same? will participants of the current call notice anything, or it's very smooth?

thanks!

Comment: ,Can you make voice calls successfully ??

Comment: yes I can. but the debugging is difficult. need to look into long ids from different sources, caller side, callee side, TwML app server console, StatusEventCallback console and twilio dashboard. it's nowhere as simple as it should be.

Comment: wangii , i want some help from you ..for making voice call in android...could please help ? actually none of the peers on SO are online regarding Twilio to help

Comment: @YogeshSeralia, yes, how?

Comment: when i make device.connect(urlParameters,connectionListers); , it gives me 
SIP registration failed (code = 302)

Comment: couple of things: 1) have you got JWT to register your device? 2) what have you got on your TwML app side when try to do device.connect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96993/discussion-between-yogesh-seralia-and-wangii).